# Node javascript array deconstruction with custom applied function

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing two strings: '1' and '5' for example. I want to save those two strings into parameters, but already as integer numbers. Currently, the code looks like this:

```js
const data = ['1', '5'];
const [min_str, max_str] = data;
const min = parseInt(min_str, 10);
const max = parseInt(max_str, 10);

console.log(typeof min_str, typeof max_str, typeof min, typeof max)
```

Is there a way to reduce this code to one line, such that *parseInt* has already been applied to *min_str* and *max_str*?

Comment: why `_str` as part of a name where the value should be a number?

Comment: Yea, that was my problem. I had to use this workaround and spent ugly names for parameters I don't actually use and wanted to get rid of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use `map()`

```
const [min_str, max_str] = data.map(x => parseInt(x, 10));
```

If the strings are only numbers inside strings. You can also use `Number`

```
const [min_str, max_str] = data.map(Number);
```

Comment: The number mapping is also useful, and I really like this approach, thanks for taking your time!

Answer (score 4):

You could map the data before destructing

```
const [min, max] = data.map(d => parseInt(d, 10));
```

Comment: Wow, thanks :) I was just formatting my question ^^

Answer (score 2):

You could get min and max values with `Math` methods.

**This approach does not rely on the order of the array nor expect only two values.**

```js
const
    data = ['1', '5'],
    [min, max] = ['min', 'max'].map(k => Math[k](...data));

console.log(min, max);
```

Comment: That's a really interesting answer

Comment: Thank you very much, that is useful and short for calculating min/max values ^^. The numbers are actually already in the right order in my array, I just need to convert them to real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the data using `Number`

```js
const [min, max] = ["1", "5"].map(Number);
console.log(min, max);
```

Answer (score 0):

const [min_str, max_str] = data.map(a => parseInt(a, 10));